# Prevent iOS 11 from centering an input element on focus

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I am working on some javascript to display interactive crosswords on websites. All the versions I have seen online (for example the New York Times’) show their own keyboard on mobile devices but I would much prefer to use the one provided by the OS or browser.

So far, I have created an `input` element that I hide by moving it offscreen to the left. (Is there a better way? Neither `display: none` nor `visibility: hidden` display the keyboard on focus.) When the user clicks on a cell in the crossword, I focus the `input` element and the keyboard pops up. Unfortunately, Safari also scrolls vertically to center the text box. This happens even when I call `input.focus({preventScroll: true})`.

Scrolling back to the position of the cell results in unpleasant jitter. The best solution I have found so far is to vertically center the `input` element myself before calling `focus` but that seems very hacky. Is there a better way?

Comment: can you share codepen link or somethink like that ?